# How a restrict users from creating multiple object on a particular resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to restrict users from having more than 1 job Application for a particular job.

Here are my routes:

```
 resources :jobs do
   resources :job_applications
 end
```

job.rb

```
 class Job < ApplicationRecord
     has_many :job_applications

     validate :limit_user_to_one_job_application

    private

   def limit_user_to_one_job_application
    if user.job_applicaitons.count > 1 
      self.errors.add(:base, "You can only have one job application")
    end 
   end 
end
```

job_application.rb

```
class JobApplication < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :job
end

user.rb
 class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :job_application

end
```

job_application_controller.rb

```
 class JobApplicationsController < ApplicationController

    before_action :authenticate_user!
      def new
        @job = Job.find(params[:job_id])
        @job_application = @job.job_applications.create

      end

      def create
        @job = Job.find(params[:job_id])
        @job_application = 
        @job.job_applications.create(job_application_params)
        @job_application.user_id = current_user.id
        @job_application.save
      end
```

in my new.html.erb file to create new job application

```
 <%= form_with(model: [ @job, @job.job_applications.build ],local: true) do |f| %>
  <%= job_application attributes %> <br>
   <%= job_application attributes %> <br>
..........

  <%= f.submit %>
```

The above code works, the user is enable to create many job applications for a particular job but only the first job in saved in his database. So ,I want the user to be restricted  to create only one job application for a particular job

Comment: Have you tried adding a validation? (Do you have any code for this?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the description mentioned in the post you can manage with uniqueness validation  in join model.

```
  class JobApplication < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :job

    validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, scope: :job_id
   end
```

This validation will prevent creation of duplicate record in the join model based on the pair for user_id and job_id.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The code provided by @Rohan works fine, it prevents the user from creating a duplicate record of the same object. Now how can I set a flash message if the user tries to create a duplicate record Or How can I just get rid of the   `<% =link_to 'APPLY,new_job_job_application_path(@job)%>` link if the user has already applied for the job

Comment: Use a helper function, something like <%= render_link @job %>  and in the function     `def render_link(job) 
    link_to('APPLY,new_job_job_application_path(job) unless JobApplication.where(user: current_user, job: job).exists?`

Comment: thanks very much, @gasc. Can you also restrict this in the URL? Like restricting the `/jobs/job_id/job_applications/new`  URL if the condition meets .Maybe redirect somewhere else

Comment: If I understand correctly, you mean that after visiting that URL, redirect if the user has already applied for the job. In that case, you can use a `before_action` in your controller. Read here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters

Comment: i created this before action and it worked. is there a shorter way of writing the code         `def restrict_duplicate_application
    job = Job.find(params[:job_id])
   unless !JobApplication.where(user: current_user, job: job).exists?
       flash[:warning] = "You have already applied for this job."
     redirect_to root_path
   end
  end`

Comment: Maybe `def restrict_duplicate_application #End Of Line    job = Job.find params[:job_id] #EOL redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path, warning: 'Already apply etc....' ) if JobApplication.where(user: current_user, job: job).exists? `

Answer (score 0):

You can do this on the controller or the model.

```
before_action :find_job, except: [:index, :new, :create]
before_action :limit_user_to_one_job_application, only: [:new, :create]

...

private

def find_job
  @job = Job.find(params[:job_id])
end 

def limit_user_to_one_job_application
  if @job.job_applications.where(:user => current_user).count == 1
    return redirect_to jobs_path, :notice => "You can only have one job application"
  end 
end
```

You'll find that it may be better to make `@job.job_applications.where(:user => current_user).count == 1` a method on `User`, but for simplicity sake I was explicit in its intent.

Or the model (something like):

```
class JobApplication < ApplicationRecord
  validate :limit_user_to_one_job_application

  private

  def limit_user_to_one_job_application
    if user.job_applicaitons.count > 1 
      self.errors.add(:base, "You can only have one job application")
    end 
  end 
end
```

Comment: Putting validations to a controller violates MVC pattern and is a bad practice.

Comment: We're not validating whether or not something should persist. We're authorizing access to an action, similarly to if we were checking that a user has created a resource and only allow them to edit said resource. It's one of the many reasons `ActionController::Callbacks` exists.

Comment: I agree with @jedi; this belongs in the model, not the controller. We **are** validating whether or not something should persist. What if there are multiple routes (e.g. other controllers or background jobs) that can create the resource? This is why you put the logic in the central point: The model. The question says "I want to restrict ... 1 application per job", not "I want to restrict **this specific action** from being able to create this (but it's fine to happen elsewhere)".

Comment: Furthermore, if you're going to add authorisation checks as an additional layer then I would use a pattern such as [`pundit`](https://github.com/varvet/pundit) to define the `JobApplicationPolicy` in **one** place rather than sprinkling this logic in multiple controllers.